# Cannot modify pandas DataFrame saved in Django model

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe, django-models

in models.py, i created this model:

```
from django.db import models
from Data.DataFrame import df  #df is the DataFrame

# Create your models here.
class Custumer(models.Model):
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    products = df
```

in the python shell, i did this:

```
In [1]: from app.models import Custumer as C

In [2]: new = C.objects.create(ip='1')

In [3]: new.products
Out[3]: 
   B000JMLBHU  B002AJ7X2C  B002D48NBO  B0031Y9CPG  B0032YXH2E  B00359FHZ6  ...  B00LDD8NDO  B00LF56Y3Q  B00LKQNFVE  B00LKS5WUY  B00LLWDUDK  B00LMTLV24       
0           0           0           0           0           0           0  ...           0           0           0           0           0           0       

[1 rows x 1000 columns]

In [4]: new.products['B000JMLBHU'] =1

In [5]: new.products
Out[5]: 
   B000JMLBHU  B002AJ7X2C  B002D48NBO  B0031Y9CPG  B0032YXH2E  B00359FHZ6  ...  B00LDD8NDO  B00LF56Y3Q  B00LKQNFVE  B00LKS5WUY  B00LLWDUDK  B00LMTLV24       
0           1           0           0           0           0           0  ...           0           0           0           0           0           0       

[1 rows x 1000 columns]

In [6]: new.save()
```

But, when i do quit() in shell and open it again, the 1 that i wrote in the first column disappears. How can i modify DataFrames saved in the model

Comment: Well you did not even define a column in the database, hence it will indeed never persist. The idea is that you need to store it, one way or another in a column, for example with a `BinaryField`.

Comment: So i cannot store entires DataFrames inside 1 model Field(without needing to loop and transform each cell of the DataFrame in some BinaryField)?

Comment: you don't need to transform every cell. You can just transform the entire dataframe, for example with a package like `parquet`. Or you can make use of a `FIleField`, and thus load/save the file with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you did not use some column to store the data and made it persistent.

You can however [define a field [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#writing-custom-model-fields) yourself that is a modified version of a [**`BinaryField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield). Then we thus need to implement some mechanism that automatically wraps between the binary representation, and the data format.

We can for example use [**`feather-format`**](https://pypi.org/project/feather-format/) to serialize and deserialize the dataframe. You install `feather-format` with:

```
pip3 install feather-format
```

Then we can define our own `DataframeField`:

```
# app/fields.py

form django.db.models import BinaryField
from io import BytesIO
from pandas import DataFrame
from pyarrow.feather as write_dataframe, read_dataframe

class DataframeField(BinaryField):

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value is None or isinstance(value, DataFrame):
            return value
        value = super().to_python(value)
        with BytesIO(value) as b:
            return read_dataframe(b)

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is None:
            return value
        value = super().from_db_value(value, expression, connection)
        with BytesIO(value) as b:
            return read_dataframe(b)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        result = value
        if isinstance(value, DataFrame):
            with BytesIO() as b:
                write_dataframe(value, b)
                result = b.getvalue()
        return super().get_prep_value(result)
```

Now we can use this field in our model to let the dataframe persist through serialization:

```
# app/models.py

from app.fields import DataframeField
from django.db import models
from Data.DataFrame import df

# Create your models here.
class Custumer(models.Model):
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    products = DataframeField(default=df)
```